# ASP.NET Web API context with foreign keys (multiple to one)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have to develop an ASP.NET Web API as a test for a job, I've never done that so I first followed the following documentation (french version sorry but basically I've been able to implement an API with a simple data model and generated automatically a controller that performs CRUD operations):

https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

What is asked me is to:

Have a first endpoint (contact) with at least:

- Firstname
- Lastname
- Fullname
- Address
- Email
- Mobile phone number

Which I have done

And a second endpoint (skills) with at least:

- Name
- Level (expertise)

So I've done 2 different model classes with the asked attribute, now the rule is "A contact can have multiple skills and a skill can belong to multiple contacts." must be implemented.

I'm struggling with this point despite the number of resources we can find on internet, I added these attributes to my "Contact" model:

```
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Skills")]
    public int? SkillsID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Skills> Skills { get; set; }
```

My current context for the Contact model looks like that:

[image]

But I can't manage to create the relationship in the Context part with the foreign key SkillsID and the table Contact.

I've tried to play around

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
```

but didn't manage to make it work.

Comment: for this you need to have ICollection<Skill>  inside Contact model and ICollection<Contact>  inside Skill model. It looks many-to-many, Ef would care for Joining or link table

Comment: Yes, I said I have added a ICollection<Skill> to Contact Model (see the post). My concern is about how to tell the context and the controller they work with a foreign key, with only the tag in the model it doesn't work. With postman I can add a skill ID that doesn't exist when calling a post on Contact endpoint.

Comment: The post is not about many-to-many and the context you share above is only handling Contact not the skill. Please checkout this
https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx
This is similar Student can have multiple courses and Course can be assigned to multiple Students

or any many-to-many tutorial similar to your case.

One more thing EF-core is different from EF-6

Comment: I checked out this tutorial, but couldn't modify the context according to my case + when I tried to modify the context the way the did (differents using), then visual studio was not able to generate the controllers...

Comment: Hmmm You have done wrong implementation (which is OK for a newbie), you need to it delete those generated controllers, views no worry because those are scaffolded or may be start it over in new project (much better as safe time) if confused. Remember don't see implementation ahead of planing.

Comment: @MohtishamZubair Your link doesn't contain any controller, how can I implement my own controller ? I guess it's necessary to have a controller in order to perform CRUD operations ?

Comment: It is same as you did by following your post.